# Easy way to list all ClassNotFound in a jar

Tags: java

**TL;DR**

Is there a utility which will analyze a .jar file and produce a list of the classes referenced in the jar which do not exist within the jar itself?

**Background**

I'm in a 15yr old code base where all jar's are checked into SCM and there's a big fat Eclipse .classpath file.

I want to convert this to Maven, but obviously I'm going to have problems where a lot of these jars are transitive dependencies of other jars in the classpath.  I just want to know the top-level jars.

My current plan of action is to build a list of classes from all jars and store them in an index.  Secondly, I need to, on a jar by jar basis, figure out all the "ClassNotFoundExceptions" which would occur if the jar was alone on the classpath.

From there I should be able to figure out a dependency graph, etc...

So my question is: How do I find out what all the ClassNotFoundExceptions would be for a given jar at run-time (i.e. all the classes it depends on which don't exist within the jar itself)

Comment: This might be a better fit on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. It seems off-topic here: "Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/238586) and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Maybe you can solve this the other way round: Add all dependencies and then use `mvn dependency:analyze` to determine which dependencies are surplus in this module.

Comment: @StevenPessall hmmm, not a bad idea.  I'll investigate that further.